# Ajax response call, 404 Not Found

Tags: ajax, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

i tried to use wordpress and codeigniter for a intelligent join between the best CMS and the best PHP Framework. Actually i intended to use codeigniter for database managemnent and wordpress for display. But i wanted to use codeigniter inside wordpress. So, i have a file tree like that:

```
www
- codigniter-core folder
  - .htaccess
- wordpress-core folder
- .htaccess
- index.php
```

How can i make the wordpress .htaccess to cover also the codeigniter ant not trowing 404 error in jquery ajax call. My current wordpress .htaccess file it's:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond $1 !^/codeigniter-core/
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

I also tried to ask this to [Wordpress Forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/340291) and Codeigniter Forums, but no answer. I think it's hell of a rewrite condition or rule, but i don't know ...

Comment: Saying "best CMS" and "best PHP Framework" is unnecessary and gives nothing to help explain your problem. Keep the question clean and share your personal feelings elsewhere, this is a technical question.

Answer (score 16):

I had this problem when creating a controller file that I would call via the jQuery ajax method. This controller file included wp-blog-header.php.

When you include the wp-blog-header.php in a file outside of WP framework WordPress does a check on the current file, and if it is not in its database it returns a 404. The work around is to add a 200 status header after the wp-blog-header.php.

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

Now (jQuery) ajax to the file returns properly without a 404.

Comment: Thank you! Was getting a 404 in a WP Ajax request and this cured it.

Answer (score 6):

This worked great... can't tell you  how long I was looking for this answer.  I suspected this had to do with a header error because firebug showed the response but the header had a 404.  Thanks this saved me a lot of time.

BTW I used this to fix the [Quick Search plugin by Giulio Ganci](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-search/)

Just open the "search.php" file in the plugin folder and add

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

Right after the first line of code.  When your done the first few lines of code in this file should look like this

```
<?php
    require('../../../wp-blog-header.php'); 
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");


    if (isset($_GET['s']) && trim($_GET['s']) != '') {
```